# Как проверить двумерный массив на упорядоченность и результат записать в новый массив?

Tags: java, массивы

Задание звучит так:

> Задать рандомный массив А[n][m]. Проверить строки массива А на упорядоченность по возрастанию и результат записать в массив B, если строка массива А упорядочена, то в массив В записывается 1, если нет, то 0. Результат вывести на экран.

С первой частью проблем не возникло, а во со второй... подскажите как правильно это сделать?

```java
import java.lang.*;

public class Mult {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите n: ");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Введите m: ");
        int m = in.nextInt();
        int[][] A = new int[n][m];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                A[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
                System.out.print(A[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно создать массив `B[]` длиной по числу строк, т.е. `n`, заполнить его единицами

Затем пройти по каждой  строке `[row]` в цикле, сравнивая `i`-й и `i+1`-й элементы на "меньше"

Если какое-то сравнение выдаёт false, нужно записать в соответствующий элемент `B[row]` ноль и прервать цикл по данной строке.

Достаточно ли такого описания?

Answer (score 0):

```java
int n = 5;
int m = 10;

int[][] arr = new int[n][m];

// заполняем массив случайными числами
IntStream.range(0, n).forEach(i ->
        IntStream.range(0, m).forEach(j ->
                arr[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 10)));

// сортируем вторую
// строку для проверки
Arrays.sort(arr[2]);

// выводим массив
Arrays.stream(arr).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
// [6, 4, 6, 0, 1, 7, 5, 4, 7, 5]
// [7, 0, 1, 9, 7, 4, 8, 8, 3, 3]
// [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 9]
// [9, 4, 7, 7, 3, 7, 9, 1, 7, 9]
// [6, 4, 3, 9, 3, 8, 0, 4, 9, 8]

// ищем отсортированные строки
// и собираем в массив
int[] res = Arrays.stream(arr).mapToInt(row -> {
    int[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(row, row.length);
    Arrays.sort(copy);
    return Arrays.equals(row, copy) ? 1 : 0;
}).toArray();

// выводим массив отсортированных строк
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
// [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```